# Minus operator with composite key

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a query to filter some of the records, but not getting how to achieve this. Below are the criteria.

I have a table `xRef` which contains no. of columns with marketId, promoId, dcId, refId. In the table the `marketId`, `promoId`, `dcId` and `refId` are the *composite* key.
 It means there could be multiple records which may exist with the same `promoId`, `marketId`, but different `dcId`.

Now I have 2 dcIds
 e.g. 10 and 15 and have rocords in table for both of these DCs.
Now I need all the records

1. Where dcId=10 and
2. promoId, marketId and refId not exists in table for dcId-15.

I tried to use the `MINUS` operator but as it's composite key, I am not able to use this. I tried with `NOT EXISTS` also, but it didn't work. May be i didn't use in proper way.

As I am not a DB guy I can't find an ultimate solution for it. So I needed help from the experts like you. Could you please help me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this query is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM xRef t1
WHERE t1.dcId = 10
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT dcId FROM xRef t2
                      WHERE t1.promoId = t2.promoId
                            AND t1.marketId = t2.marketId
                            AND t1.refId = t2.refId
                            AND t2.dcId = 15)
```